# Gnu Prolog does not accept any user definitions

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog.  I have installed Gnu Prolog 1.4.4 on my Mac.  I was directly following the example given in the [Gnu Prolog Manual](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec10), section 4.2.3, "Consulting a Prolog program," but I am not getting the expected results:

```
Compiled Sep 26 2016, 00:06:17 with clang
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
even(0).
even(s(s(X))) :- even(X).
/* Hit Ctl-D here. */
user compiled, 3 lines read - 360 bytes written, 19084 ms

(1 ms) yes
| ?- even(X).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,even/1),top_level/0)
```

I am getting the same (bad) results when I use an external file with my definitions.  Any idea what is going wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the example. Likely something wrong with the compilation of GNU Prolog itself. How did you installed/compiled it?

Comment: brew install gnu-prolog .

Comment: Can you uninstall it and try instead the binary installer that you can download from the GNU Prolog website?